# Apache,may I have multiple documentRoot?

Tags: apache, zend-framework, document-root

I'm building a Zend website.The project (local) has the following structure:

```
/app
  /controllers
  /views

  /public
   /css
   /images
   /js
   .htaccess
   index.php
```

Because the .htaccess and index.php files reside within th public directory,the public directory must be identifiable by apache as the website's document root and root directory.

So I should go to edit the "DocumentRoot from c:/wamp/www/ to c:/wamp/www/my-zend-app/public" inside the httpd.conf file.
But if I do so I can't reach my other projects inside "c:/wamp/www/".. can I keep both the documentRoots?

**EDIT**
I tried with uncommenting the httpd.conf line about "httpd-vhost.conf" and edited the file:

[httpd-vhost.conf]

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dum.com
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\my-zend-app\application\public"
ServerName website.loc
ErrorLog "C:\wamp\www\my-zend-app\application\public\error.log"
CustomLog "C:\wamp\www\my-zend-app\application\access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

right after edited the windows hosts file adding:

```
127.0.0.1 website.loc
```

but it's not working.I'm running WAMPSERVER 2.1

Comment: Use an [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) if you need a root lower down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `<Directory>` [Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) to your `<VirtualHost>` directive for the new document root

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/my-zend-app/application/public">
        Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a second virtual host using a different port or using ServerName (and editing hosts file to resolve locally.

The easier one is just using different virtual hosts on different ports but remember also adding `Listen yourPort` on the main config to make apache listen that port too.